# Probablity theore

Tags: probability-theory

Consider an experiment whose sample space con sists of a countably infinite number of points.  Show that not all points can be equally likely.  Can all points have a positive probability of occurring?

Answer (score 3):

Let $S=\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ the sample space.
Assume that all the points are equally likely, and let $p$ their probability, i.e. $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $P(X=x_n) = p$.

$p$ cannot be $0$, otherwise $P(X\in S)$ would be equal to $0$, and it should be $1$, as $P$ is a probability.
But if $p>0$, $1=P(X\in S) =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}P(X=x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}p=+\infty$ and we get another contradiction.

All points can have a positive probability of occuring though. Think about the standard Poisson distribution whose sample space is $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, with $P(X=k) = \frac{1}{ek!}$.